# Startup Applications in settings resets when settings i closed

Tags: settings

I have tried for the last week to get my startup applications to change, but for some reason every time I try to change the settings nothing happens. The next time I open the settings the startup applications is back to before I edited it.
I also tried the gnome-session-properties to see if something was wrong with the Eos settings. 
I do not know how to fix it, and I am out of ideas. Do anybody have an idea?

Comment: I suggest you file an issue here at [https://github.com/elementary/switchboard/issues](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard/issues)

Comment: I will do that to the applications plugin.